# Membership Profile in .NET ASP, Is it fast to access or better to use alternatives?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, profiler

What is everyones thoughts on using the built in ASP Membership Profile with Forms to retrieve user ID for web applications. I understand it makes accessing the user GUID very easy, but is retrieving that value from the SQL server every time a practical, fast option?

Would it be better to store it in say a cookie and if that cookie fails, then retrieve from the database? what are peoples thoughts on this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. a Profiler is a tool to analyze the performance for an application, that has nothing to do with user guids, i guess you meant "profile", but your purpose is missing, making it hard to help you.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, Membership Profiler

Answer (score 0):

Well I was just leaving this as a comment because I think your question is going to be flagged as too general but my comment is getting to long so here is an answer instead:

You concerns are a none issue in this day and age. I have never even used ASP.NET membership before but I intend to for a current project of mine even though I have a custom built light weight membership library that is mature and I have used for years, why? Because the ASP.NET membership is already in the project when I created it so it will be quicker to setup than importing my custom library and making tweaks and changes. Also, using ASP.NET Membership has Anti-forgery token for AJAX requests which is more advanced stuff than my library has for added security.

Passing GUIDS around is a non issue because even in lower bandwidth scenarios it is just not a big deal and obviously, in this day and age of cheap hardware, the increased memory and database storage compared to using an int, for example as an id, is just not even worth thinking about except on the level of conserving energy (server consumption, bandwidth consumption all eats a little energy right?)

The only problem with a guid is that it is less human readable and slightly more time consuming to copy and paste to query the database for a specific user to get information about the user or debug in sql server management studio but you get used to it in about 20 minutes. As far as guid type and passing guids around, it is just as easy as managing integers in C#.

So to sum, it is a non issue unless you our an ultimate tree hugger trying to give a couple minutes of extra heat to your great great great great great great grandchildren right before the next ice age.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your needs.

For the very basic approach you could just use [FormsAuthentification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [How to implement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Basicaly its just to say if(isAuthenticated) [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and for logoff use [SignOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If your needs are a little bigger than that go and have a look at [MembershipReboot](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot)

And look here for alittle background on why not to use [MembershipProvider](http://brockallen.com/2012/09/02/think-twice-about-using-membershipprovider-and-simplemembership/)

Answer (score 0):

> is retrieving that value from the SQL server every time a practical, fast option?

No, it's entirely too slow to use in any project, that's why it's been part of ASP.NET for the last eight years or so and been used in tons of intranet and internet applications.

Do you have any actual concerns, then benchmark it. It depends on your site, database and server architecture. If performance really becomes an issue, you can build a custom provider on top of it that implements caching. Cookies have nothing to do with that.